# C program to calc avg etc

Tags: c

i wrote this code in class today with the teacher helping me but I'm home now and need guidance, I'm not sure what i should do next to get it to compile atleast

the objective is to:

create a menu
enter a number(option A)
dispaly the average (option B)
display the highest and lowest number(option C and D)
display the total of all numbers entered(option E)
display the total amount of numbers entered(option F)
and quit(option G)

here is what i have so far, i apologies if its messy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//int getNumber (aNumber) {
 //   printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 1000.\n");
//    scanf("%i", &aNumber);
 //   int result;
 //   }
char getMenuLetter();
int getNumber();
//declare variables

int aNumber = 0;
float avg = 0.0;
int high = -1;
int low = 1001;
int total = 0;
int count = 0;
char getChoice = 'x';

int main() {

//proptotype functions



do {
    getChoice = getMenuLetter();

    switch (getChoice)
           case 'A':
           aNumber = getNumber();
           count++;
           total += aNumber;
           low = testLow(aNumber, low)
           high = testHigh(aNumber, high);
                        break;
           case 'B';
           avg = (double) total/count; //display avg
           printf("The average is %.2f", avg);
                       break;
           case 'C':
           high = getHigh();
           printf("The highest value of all the numbers entered is %i.\n", high); //display highest number
                       break;
           case 'D':
           low = getLow;
           printf("The lowest value of all the numbers entered is %i.\n", low); //displayer lowest value
                       break;
           case 'E':
           printf("The total of all the numbers entered is %i.\n", total);
                       break;
           case 'F':
           printf("The amount of numbers entered so far is %i.\n", count);
           case 'G';
                       break: //end switch


} while (userChoice != 'G');

}

int testLow(int n) {
    int result;

    if (n < low)
          result = n;
    else

    return 0;

} //End of main

char getMenuLetter() {
     char result;
     system("cls") //clear the screen.

     printf("*************************************************\n");
     printf("A) Enter a number between 0 and 1,000\n");
     printf("B) Display the average\n");
     printf("C) Display the highest value entered\n");
     printf("D) Display the lowest value entered\n");
     printf("E) Display the sum of all numbers\n");
     printf("F) Display the count of all numbers entered\n");
     printf("G) Quit the program\n");
     printf("*************************************************\n");
     scanf("%c", &result);
     result =toupper(result);
///print f %c 
//system pause

if (result != 'A' || result != 'B' || result !='C' || result !='D' || result !='E' || result != 'F' || result !='G'){
            printf("You must enter A - G only! \n)");
            system("pause");
 } //end if

} while(result != 'A' || result != 'B' || result !='C' || result !='D' || result !='E' || result != 'F' || result !='G');
     return result;
     //end of GetMenuLetter
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this yet?  If so, you'd see where your problems are.  There are tons.  I'd start there, try to work out as many errors as possible, then ask for help where you're terribly stuck.

Comment: in testLow function: it should if(n < low) return n; else return low; and if you are going to use the global variable low in it, then you can remove the argument L. First thing I see.

Comment: Okay thank u for tips, i fixed the testLow function. Im stuck on how to write the function for testLow tho, any advice?

Comment: Read the answers below.  I gave you some hints.  And also, @mekel, you should spell out all your words here to avoid confusion.  Instead of "tho" you can spell "though."  Programming is full of a lot of acronyms and abbreviations as is, so reducing your English words won't help us help you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest:

1. **Compile your program first.**  Your compiler will return most of your errors (the important ones, at least).
2. **Pay attention to your use of curly bases.**  In C (and in many other languages), the compiler will treat lines that follow other lines linearly.  The curly braces cause a multidimensional interpretation. As a beginner to programming, you should practice using curly braces where you can, just so you get into the habit of segregating instructions.  Also, you should pay close attention to **matching** your open curly braces with your closed curly braces.  For more information, you should see the [**C Standard, 6.8: Statements and Blocks**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).
3. Your `switch()` block should end with a `default:` value, just in case you reach a choice that's unexpected.
4. I don't suggest putting your functions prototype inside your `main()` procedure.  It has to do with scopes.  Check this out, from **Section 6.2.1** of the standard.

> 2  For each different entity that an identiﬁer designates, the identiﬁer
>   is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text
>   called its scope. Different entities designated by the same identiﬁer
>   either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces. There
>   are four kinds of scopes: function, ﬁle, block, and function
>   prototype. (A function prototype is a declaration of a function that
>   declares the types of its parameters.)

I don't know what else to tell you.  Try what I proposed in order.  Make sure you read the standard though.  As a final suggestion: try programming in a more ordered manner.  Your code won't look so sloppy if you keep coding under the intent of wanting to make something you can read by the time you're finished.

Good luck.

Comment: @tenfour haha Maybe one day!  I'll be just as good as you are in C.  That's the plan.  No saint until then!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- Check your compiler errors and warnings beginning with the first.
- Switch on additional warnings of your compiler (e.g. parameters `-W -Wall` for gcc).
- There is a significant difference between "`;`" and "`:`" in C.
- The body of a `switch` statement  has to be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: `-Wall` does not switch on all gcc warnings: it switches on "warnings that some users consider questionable"; it includes `-Wmissing-braces` which I don't like and it doesn't include a whole lot of warnings I like (eg `-Wfloat-equal`).

Comment: @pmg: Got me. I always use `-W -Wall -pedantic -ansi` without knowing/caring what exactly it means.

Comment: Having `-Wall` is much better than having no warning option at all :p

Comment: do you have any advice on how to declare the function testLow?

Comment: @mekel: Not sure I understand your question, but the declaration of `testLow` would be "`int testLow(int n);`" and should be put somewhere above `main`. Also note that in `main` (`case 'D'`) you are not calling that function; the parentheses (function call operator) are missing.

Comment: thank u fixed those two errors but now the debugger is saying that i have too many arguments before testLow

Comment: @mekel: You are calling testLow with 2 parameters (`aNumber` and `low`), so its declaration and definition should have two parameters as well: `int testLow(int n, int low)`. Note also that the implementation is wrong. It should return `low` instead of 0 in the second case.